# How to align multiple equations with correct numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, subequations

I am trying to align multiple equations together. I am attempting todo this by using sub equations but I want the numbering to be normal such that it doesn't go up like 1a & 1b but 1 & 2. Is this possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Amsmath example}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{May 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{subequations} \label{eq1}
\begin{alignat}{2}
A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Am I attempting this is the wrong way?

Comment: Don't use `subequations` around the math environment.

Comment: It's not clear to me why `alignat` is used here.  `align` in this situation would get the same result, and be simpler, thus better.  Reading the `amsmath` documentation would be beneficial.

Comment: Oh ok apologies, thats just the example demonstrated on Overleaf so just used it in the same manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `subequations` you'll get subequations, if you don't use it, you'll get normal equation numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Amsmath example}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{May 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{alignat}{2}
A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]